# FileNotFoundError In ImageTk

Tags: python, image, tkinter

im creating a slideshow program in tkinter

my code :

```
    folder_path=fd.askdirectory(initialdir=os.getcwd(),title="Open Directory")
    for i in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if i.endswith(".jpg") or i.endswith(".png") or i.endswith(".jpeg"):
            new_image=Image.open(i)
            new_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=new_image)
            canvas.image=new_image
            canvas.create_image(0,0,image=new_image,anchor=tk.NW)
            time.sleep(5)
```

when im running it, im getting FileNotFoundError:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\speed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\speed\Documents\Text Editor In PyQt5\wmi_test.py", line 13, in open_file
    new_image=Image.open(i)
  File "C:\Users\speed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2968, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2021-09-04_13.png'
```

Comment: You need to join `folder_path` and the filename to get a full path name and use it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update this line by adding the path of the file:

```
 new_image=Image.open(folder_path+"\"+i)
```

Comment: it works! `new_image=Image.open(folder_path+"//"+i)`

Comment: Better use `os.path.join()` as it caters the folder separator across platforms.