# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image1.jpg'

Tags: python

file not found error when I try to use the image as a background for my page

```
   from PIL import ImageTk, Image
   import tkinter
   import customtkinter

   customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
   customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("green")

   app = customtkinter.CTk()
   app.geometry("600x440")
   app.title("Login")
  
   img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image1.png'))
   l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, image=img1)
   l1.pack()
   
   app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Be sure whether the file exists in the folder from where you are running the above script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundError In ImageTk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016945/filenotfounderror-in-imagetk)

Comment: Please search this site for the exact error message "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 0):

please check image1.png exists into your public folder? if it is inside any subfolder like /images/image1.png so correct path of that image.